Using comma separated list to ssh
Following on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511859/374303,
whose answer is:
while IFS=, read -r IP ID NAME; do 
    echo "ssh $IP myprogram $ID $NAME"
done < testfile.txt

However, my question is not doing echo but doing the actual ssh:
while IFS=, read -r IP ID NAME; do 
    ssh $IP myprogram $ID $NAME
done < testfile.txt

Yet, that won't work any more as only the first line is read from testfile.txt, and the rest of the lines are gone after ssh was called.
Any easy solution please?

that sounds like your myprogram consumes input. That's not a shell problem, but a myprogram problem, and you sadly haven't told us what that does.

Does it work if you use ssh -n $IP myprogram $ID $NAME?

@MarcusMüller, ssh will consume (quite at lot of) the input even if myprogram doesn't read its stdin. Try with yes | strace -e read ssh localhost 'sleep 20' for instance.

Beware ssh $IP myprogram $ID $NAME is an ACE vulnerability if the contents of those variables are not fully controlled, it's like running sh -c "myprogram $ID $NAME" or eval "myprogram $ID $NAME", but remotely.
